# Setting proper query for multiple custom admin filters

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, filters, meta-query, admin-bar

I am adding custom admin filters for my custom post types. I am a bit confused about how to go with the `parse_query` filter in order to have my posts filtered based on 2 or more filters.

Initially for 1 filter, I can do:

```
$query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'city';
$query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $cityId;
$query->query_vars['meta_compare'] = '=';
```

and I will get my filtered results.

I am wondering, if WP would accept more meta_keys/values for the query_vars...

I am trying to set a `meta_query` and below is what I have done - but it doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'wpr_manager_filter' );
function  wpr_manager_filter($query) {
  global $page;
  $current_page = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';

  if ( is_admin()
    && 'properties' == $current_page
    && 'edit.php' == $page
  )
  {
    $metaQuery = array();
    if (isset( $_GET['city-filter'] ) && $_GET['city-filter'] != '-1')
    {
      $cityId = (int)$_GET['city-filter'];
      $metaQuery['relation'] = 'AND';
      $metaQuery[] = array(
        'meta_key' => 'city',
        'meta_value' => $cityId,
        'meta_compare' => '='
      );

      // $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'city';
      // $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $cityId;
      // $query->query_vars['meta_compare'] = '=';
    }
    if (isset( $_GET['visibility-filter'] ) && $_GET['visibility-filter'] != '-1')
    {
      $visibility = (int)$_GET['visibility-filter'];
      $metaQuery[2] = array(
        'meta_key' => 'visibility',
        'meta_value' => $visibility,
        'meta_compare' => '='
      );
    }
    $query->meta_query = $metaQuery;
  }
}
```

It has been a long day, and I have just start getting more familiar with deeper WP concepts, so any kind of help that will push me forward and will explain me what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my final working piece of code:

```
function  wpr_manager_filter($query) {
  global $pagenow;
  global $typenow;

  $current_page = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';

  if ( is_admin()
    && 'properties' == $typenow
    && 'edit.php' == $pagenow
  )
  {
    $queryParamsCounter = 0;
    if (isset( $_GET['city-filter'] ) && $_GET['city-filter'] != '-1')
    {
      $cityId = (int)$_GET['city-filter'];
      $queryParamsCounter++;
    }
    if (isset( $_GET['visibility-filter'] ) && $_GET['visibility-filter'] != '-1')
    {
      $queryParamsCounter++;
      $visibility = (int)$_GET['visibility-filter'];
    }

    $meta_query = array();

    if ($queryParamsCounter > 1) {
      $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';
    }

    if (isset($cityId)) {
      $meta_query[] =       array(
        'key'     => 'city',
        'value'   => $cityId,
        'compare' => '=',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
      );
    }
    if (isset($visibility)) {
      $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'visibility',
        'value'   => $visibility,
        'compare' => '=',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
      );
    }

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query);
  }
}
```

May someone else find it useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the end of your code: `$query->meta_query = $metaQuery;`.

`meta_query` is a property of `$query_var` array. So the coreect one should be:

```
$query->query_vars['meta_query'] = $metaQuery;
```